# including a .c file in another .c file

Tags: gcc, include, makefile

This is part of a homework assignment. What we have to do is write a makefile to compile previous homework solutions. The solutions were provided by the professor, and they're what will be used to test our makefiles. One of the files has an `#include "quicksort.c"`.

I know the usage of something like that is discouraged, but that doesn't really help me :)

What would be the best approach to getting the two files to compile (the file `quicksortTest.c`, which includes `quicksort.c`, and `quicksort.c` itself)?

What I currently have as part of my makefile is the following:

```
    quicksort: quicksort.c quicksortTest.c
               $(CC) quicksortTest.c quicksort.c -o quicksortTest
```

Where `quicksortTest.c` has the `#include "quicksort.c"`.

When I try it, I get several gcc compiler errors... ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass `quicksort.c` to `gcc`.  Since you are including the file you should not compile it seperately:

```
quicksort: quicksort.c quicksortTest.c
       $(CC) quicksortTest.c -o quicksortTest
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
quicksort: quicksort.c quicksortTest.c
           $(CC) quicksortTest.c -o quicksortTest
```

Consider giving your teacher a C book.

Comment: For testing code, it can be sensible to `#include` C source in order to gain access to the internals of the source from the test harness.  Otherwise, you usually don't include C source files, you're right.  It is tempting to give the teacher a C book; it might not be politic, though.